# Drop Down List on different aspx pages need to "relate" to one another

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The issue I'm running into isn't an emergency but I don't know how to do it. I have two aspx webform pages. There is a drop down list on each. Both are populated by the same datasource from sql server. The issue is, if I select a value on page 1, then go to page 2, it repopulates the drop down list (because it is being populated from the datasrouce). For example, if page 2 drop down list is Hamilton, and then click on page 2 Hamilton needs to be shown. Currently it will display the first record in the database. This is just becoming more of a user friendly feature and isn't much of an issue. I do no know where to being really on this one, so I do not have any code to show. This seems to be kind of a unique problem as I could not find any forums on this. I'm not sure if jQuery would be a valid way of doing this or not.  Here is the way that I am populating the drop down lists during the page load..

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    //Session["dship"] = ddlDealershipRec.SelectedIndex;

    conn.Open();

    //This selects the user's ID where the user name equals the user that is currently logged in. 
    SqlCommand cmdUserID = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserID from Users WHERE UserName = '" + User.Identity.Name + "'", conn);
    selectUserID = Convert.ToString(cmdUserID.ExecuteScalar());

    //Selections the location ID where the userID is equal the the UserName.
    SqlCommand cmdLocationID = new SqlCommand("SELECT LocationID from UserControl WHERE UserID = '" + selectUserID + "'", conn);
    selectLocationID = Convert.ToString(cmdLocationID.ExecuteScalar());

    //Selects the Coporate or Store where the userID is equal to the UserName.
    SqlCommand cmdCorporateStore = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(CorporateStore) from Users WHERE UserID = '" + selectUserID + "'", conn);
    selectCorporateStore = Convert.ToString(cmdCorporateStore.ExecuteScalar());

    //Selects if the user is an Admin.
    SqlCommand cmdAdmin = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Admin) from Users WHERE UserID = '" + selectUserID + "'", conn);
    selectAdmin = Convert.ToString(cmdAdmin.ExecuteScalar());

    conn.Close();

    //use to display "Garage" when an admin logs in.
    if (selectAdmin == "Yes")
    {
        Control allUsers = this.Page.Master.FindControl("login").FindControl("loginview").FindControl("ulmenu").FindControl("allUsers");
        allUsers.Visible = true;
    }

    gvVehicleTEMP.ControlStyle.Font.Size = 8;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlDealershipRec.Items.Clear();
        List<int> locationIDList = new List<int>();
        List<string> locationList = new List<string>();

        conn.Open();

        //used to populate the dropDownList depending who is logged in. 
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdLocationID.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int locationID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                locationIDList.Add(locationID);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        foreach (int id in locationIDList)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdLocation = new SqlCommand("SELECT LocationName FROM Location WHERE LocationID = '" + id + "' ORDER BY LocationName ASC", conn);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdLocation.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string location = reader.GetString(0);
                    locationList.Add(location);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        foreach (string location in locationList)
        {
            ddlDealershipRec.Items.Add(new ListItem(location));
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I have added my entire page load from my first page. As you can see, a lot is going on here and it is database driven like crazy. I had to do somethings differently than ever expected because I'm using Forms Authentication with Active Directory. The select cmdLocationID is used to get data from my "UserControl" table. This table only has two columns, UserID and LocationID. Since my UserID is 1, and I have all the 7 or 8 stores there are 7 or 8 UserID with 1 and it relates to a store. I then save it to a string and add it to the locations lists basically then populate the drop down list.

Comment: You basically just need to post back that ID from the ddl. From there, you set the selected item of the ddl on page 2 to whatever the ID was that was just posted back. If you show some code on how you're getting data back to the controller, we can give you more specific help.

Comment: @JonLaMarr The above is the way that I am populating the drop down lists on both pages. I have 8 records in table that, once on page load, adds the items in the list to the drop down list. As you can see in my foreach loop at the end, it adds the location that the user has access to. If the user has access to two locations, then only those two are populated in the drop down. I have access to all locations so I see all locations once I log in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

From a high level view, what you can do is save the selection's unique identifier (like the DropDownList's SelectedIndex) into the user state, then when the other page loads, match the DropDownList to that unique identifier.

[There are many ways to save information in user state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx). One way is in Session State. Here's how to save information in Session State:

```
Session["VariableName"] = (int)ddlNameOfDropdownList.SelectedIndex;
```

Then you can access that Session variable on another page at another time (they time out within 20 minutes by default, so if your form is taking longer than that, you may want to use something like ViewState).

To access the session variable and use it on another page, inside the PageLoad you could add:

```
ddlOtherDropdownList.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["VariableName"]);
```

I've left out checking for nulls when you access the session variable, but those are auxiliary issues.

**EDIT:** Added an explicit cast.

**EDIT:** You would want to add a click event to the button on the first page that redirects you to the second page like so:

```
void btnToSecondPage_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["dropdownSelected"] = (int)ddlDealershipRec.SelectedIndex;
    Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx");
}
```

This saves the selected index as a session variable before going to the next page. Then, on the second page load, after you've populated the ddlDealershipRec, you would want this:

```
ddlDealershipRec.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["dropdownSelected");
```

Comment: Cool. I just gave this a shot. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting a Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?) in the second page that is using the ddlOtherDropDownList.SelectedIndex = Session["VariableName"]; and the error is underlining the Session["VariableName"]. Am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: I added the Convert.ToInt32 which got rid of the error but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You can cast any object using the () syntax. So, instead of using `Session["VariableName"]` you would use `(int)Session["VariableName"]`. That's an implicit cast. 

An explicit cast (which is stronger) would be `Convert.ToInt32(Session["VariableName"])`.

How did that not solve the issue? Are there errors or is it logically not working? Debugging can be a great help in seeing what is wrong.

Comment: It's logically not working. It's almost there, but not quite. If the third value in the drop down is selected and I click my "Show All" button, it populates my grid like always. Then I go to the second page, the drop down list shows all of the values in but it defaults to show the very first one. But when I click "Show All" on this page, it then will go to the third value, but I'm unable to change the value to a different one.

Comment: It sounds like the code to set the index needs to be in a different point in the lifecycle or possibly within a click event.

I would heavily suggest reading about the ASP.NET lifecycle. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx

Comment: I have tried your edited solution. I'm getting an error at locationIDList saying that it does not exist in the current it's in the page load so it's not being accessed in the button click. I move it above the page load but then another error occurs at the .selectedindex asking if I am missing a assembly or reference? This turns out to be pretty frustrating.

Comment: After looking at your code again, I realized that locationIDList is NOT the DropDownList control. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, it is customary to accept the answer. If this has not answered your problem, let's continue working on getting it solved.

Comment: Sorry, I got side tracked with another project. I have tried what you have explained. What happens is that, if I click on the drop down and select a value, and then click show all, it displays all the results from that drop down. Then when I go to the next page, the drop down within that page defaults back to the first value. But if I click the show all button on that page, it does change the drop down value from the first page and shows the results for that value. But then I'm unable to view any other values' results if I change the drop down.